# SEDE login loops back to "log in" link

Tags: support, data-explorer, login, user-accounts

I tried to log in to https://data.stackexchange.com/ and it appeared to succeed, but it didn't show my profile pic in the upper right, just the "log in" link.

I selected the "Log in using Stack Exchange" link on the login page, and it didn't even ask me for my password, just looped back to the start page. My profile was still not activated, and the "log in" link was still visible in its place.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too (twice, as of last week). The solution was simply to remove the two cookies created by the data.stackexchange.com website and try again.

[image]

Comment: I had more than two. I deleted them all, and things are now working -- thanks! Still hoping for someone from SE to look into this.

Answer (score 1):

I find this occurs if I happen to have SEDE open at the 24-hour mark after last login.

It's as if SEDE knows I'm no longer authorized, but doesn't know what to do with the expired token.  Another symptom of the same problem is when I'll try to run a query, it will finish instantly, but without producing query results or an error.

(Caution - at this point your changes aren't being saved either!)

**To fix the issue**, I usually just:

1. click Logout (if available)
2. close the browser
3. re-open browser
4. log back in to SEDE.

Worst comes worst, just reboot your machine.